# the values in the form arent being added into database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to get values to be entered into my database called "Quiz" with rows "ID, name, question, answer, useranswer" however, I can't seem to get the values to be entered into the table. Can someone please have a look at my code and direct me as to where it is going wrong. I am just a beginner and am not too familiar with PHP and mySQL.

```
    <form method = "post" action = "create.php">
        <div = "input-group">
            <label for = "name"> Quiz Name: </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "name" name = "name" value = "<?php echo $name; ?>" onsubmit = "return validateform()"></input>

            <label for = "question"> Question: </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "question" name = "question" value = "<?php echo $question; ?>"></input>

            <label for = "answer"> Answer: </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "answer" name = "answer" value = "<?php echo $answer;?>"></input>

            <input type = "submit" class = "btn" name = "quiz"</input>
        </div>
    </form>
```

the code above is the form that is being passed through the PHP file.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['quiz'])) {

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $question = $_POST['question'];
        $answer = $_POST['answer'];


        $db = mysqli_connect('host', 'username', 'password', 'database') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server')
            $query = "INSERT INTO Quiz(name, question, answer) VALUES('$name', '$question', '$answer')";
            $result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');
            mysqli_close($db);
        echo "1 record added";
    };
?>
```

the code above is the connection to my database and would be used to add the values in, if it worked.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: Your input button code is not correct: Use this and try: <input type="submit" class="btn" name="quiz">

Comment: missing a semicolon after `$db = mysqli_connect(...`

Comment: The first thing in debugging is to find where it is going wrong, especially when working on web platform where you have a mixture of HTML, JavaScript, PHP, etc. So you need to know these steps are working correctly:

does HTML passes the data to PHP?
does PHP receive the data?
does PHP correctly send data to database?

Comment: @KamyarMirzavaziri  already point some error in code, if still not working put these lines at the top and you will see errors/warnings ``ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); ``

Comment: Thanks guys, I have managed to solve my problem, I ended up using a different code form all together as I couldn't manage to get it working :)